# Object drag delay issue

Tags: javascript, dom, drag-and-drop

I have this code that drags stuff around perfectly in IE - however in firefox the onmousedown-drag of the object does not immediately drag but shows the no-entry cursor and then after onmouseup the object drags around freely. The object does stop draging on the next onmouseup. The object should only drag in the onmousdown state, while the onmousup call should cancel the drag by making j_OK=0. I think it may have something to do with the image inside...

the object:

```
    <em style=position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:32;height:32;display:block>
< img src=abc.gif onmousedown=P_MV(this.parentNode) style=position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:inherit>
</em>



    function P_MV(t)
{
 p_E=t
 j_oy=parseInt(p_E.style.top)
 j_ox=parseInt(p_E.style.left)
 j_OK=1
 document.onselectstart=function(){return false}
 document.onmousemove=P_MVy
}

function P_MVy(e)
{
 if(j_OK)
 {
  p_E.style.top=(j_FF?e.clientY:event.clientY)-j_y+j_oy
  p_E.style.left=(j_FF?e.clientX:event.clientX)-j_x+j_ox
 }
 return false
}
```

Comment: The code looks like it came out of an obfuscater...  By the way, it's good code practice to stick an end-of-statement semicolon, even though JavaScript doesn't require it [it makes your code look cleaner]...  In addition, when defining an attribute of an html element in code, stick a quotes around it, to maintain readability >_<

Comment: j_y and j_x are never defined in your code?  BTW, P_MV makes me think of p=mv... [momentum]

Comment: @ItzWarty: Not only does adding semicolons make your code look cleaner, it keeps the code from getting messed up when minified.

Comment: sorry about omitting j_y and j_x declarations - these are set onmousedown and are the x and y positions of the click

Answer (score 0):

You can't just blithely use clientX and clientY. Those properties work differently among IE and other browsers. As [quirksMode says,](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html) there is more to do just to get the correct location. Here's his solution:

```
function doSomething(e) {
    var posx = 0;
    var posy = 0;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY)     {
        posx = e.pageX;
        posy = e.pageY;
    }
    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
        posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
            + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
            + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    // posx and posy contain the mouse position relative to the document
    // Do something with this information
}
```

Comment: this answers the issue of cleint XY but not the question asked...even with this code inserted the issue remains.